# Meteor - export npm function (module pattern)

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to sanitize HTML, using [sanitize-html](https://github.com/punkave/sanitize-html#sanitize-html) via npm.

I'd like to use import/export in a module-pattern, in order not to reconfigure the function every time I need it.

I try the code below, but get `Uncaught TypeError: bob is not a function` every time.

Surely obvious but can you help?

**module (sanitHTML.js)**

```
import sanitizeHtml from 'sanitize-html';    
export const bob = (dirty) => {
       var clean = sanitizeHtml(dirty, {
          allowedTags: [ 'b', 'i', 'em', 'strong', 'a' ],
          allowedAttributes: {
            'a': [ 'href' ]
          }
        }); 
       return clean;
    }
```

**function call**

```
import {bob} from '../modules/sanitHTML.js'; // import sanitize HTML function
import sanitizeHtml from 'sanitize-html';

[...]

var cleantext = bob(dirtytext);
console.log (cleantext);
```

Comment: did you import sanitizeHtml in sanitHTML.js?

Comment: @Meldon yes - in both files actually, no change.

Comment: Hmm.. I have no problem running the code (I set out `sanitizeHtml` like so `function sanitizeHtml() { return 'test'; }`). Can you try exporting something else, like `export const foo = 'bar';` and see if you can access that from another file?

Comment: You're right @Meldon: it was an import problem. I just renamed `sanitHTML.js` in `sanit.js` and it works. Surely an issue with `xxxhtml.js` filename...

Comment: also the `import sanitizeHtml from 'sanitize-html';` is only necessary in the module file (`sanit.js`)

Comment: Yes, you only have to import it where it's used in the code. Glad you figured it out :)